# Is there a way to make MSAA IAccessible traversal faster?

Tags: c++, winapi, accessibility, msdn

Right now I have this C++ function (removed safety checks and some code to make it more readable):

```
HRESULT WalkTreeWithAccessibleChildren(wstringstream *ss, IAccessible* pAcc, int depth)
{
    long childCount;
    long returnCount;   

    VARIANT* pArray = new VARIANT[childCount];
    hr = AccessibleChildren(pAcc, 0L, childCount, pArray, &returnCount);
    for (int x = 0; x < returnCount; x++) {
        VARIANT vtChild = pArray[x];
        Get the role and name of the component here
        // If it's an accessible object, get the IAccessible, and recurse.
        if (vtChild.vt == VT_DISPATCH) {
            IDispatch* pDisp = vtChild.pdispVal;
            IAccessible* pChild = NULL;
            hr = pDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IAccessible, (void**) &pChild);
            WalkTreeWithAccessibleChildren(ss, pChild, depth + 1);
    }
}
```

For some programs with relatively few components (200 or so), e.g. Paint.NET, this takes about 2 full seconds, is there a way I can make this function faster, get all of the components in one COM call or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

It depends somewhat on what you are trying to do.

If you are looking for a specific item, you can sometimes use navigation(accNavigate) to get to an item faster rather than looking through all of the items.

If you really need to get all of the items, background threading works well.

Another option is to use the UIAutomation api it still supports all IAccessible servers, and it has richer caching and filtering built into it.  Look on MSDN for IUIAutomationCacheRequest and it's methods TreeFilter and TreeScope for more information.  It also has a way to search for specific items if you are in the specific item case.

Think of UIAutomation as a superset of IAccessible.  UIAutomation is available on Vista SP2 and above.

Comment: Using UIAutomation is not an option unfortunately (needs to work for XP with service pack 2), and accNavigate doesn't seem to be any faster than the way I'm getting the children right now (it's also deprecated). Thanks for your response though. How will background threads increase the speed of execution? Wouldn't they make things slower?

Comment: Background threading won't make the overall process of getting the items faster but sometimes it can be used to make the UI more responsive making something seem faster than it really is.

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318473(v=vs.85).aspx) states that `The accNavigate method is deprecated and should not be used`.